# How To Automate Slider in Selenium Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Hi I am trying to automate https://emicalculator.net/
.I tried many approach but did not get success Below is my code for automating Interest rate slider

```
package seleniumBasics;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class AdjustSliderValue {
    static String baseUrl = "https://emicalculator.net/";
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public WebDriver createDriver() {
        driver = DriverSetup.getWebDriver();
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        return driver;
    }

     @AfterMethod
    public void CloseDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public static int GetPixelsToMove(WebElement Slider, double Amount, double SliderMax, double SliderMin) {
        int pixels = 0;
        int tempPixels = Slider.getSize().getWidth();
        System.out.println(tempPixels);
        tempPixels = (int)(tempPixels / (SliderMax - SliderMin));
        System.out.println(tempPixels);
        tempPixels = (int) (tempPixels * (Amount - SliderMin));
        System.out.println(tempPixels);
        pixels = tempPixels;
        return pixels;
    }



    @Test
    public static void verifySlider() throws InterruptedException {
    
        WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loaninterestslider\"]"));
        

        int PixelsToMove = GetPixelsToMove(Slider, 15, 20, 5);
        Actions SliderAction = new Actions(driver);
        SliderAction.clickAndHold(Slider).moveByOffset((-(int) Slider.getSize().getWidth() / 2), 0)
                .moveByOffset(PixelsToMove, 0).release().perform();

}
}
```

**I want a method which can automate any slider. Could any one who knows please help me. Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

You may also try Key actions using Send Keys

```
// Set Loop counter to get desired value
   <Your_Slider_Element>.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT); // Or ARROW_RIGHT
// End loop
```

Answer (score 0):

dragAndDropBy usually work best with slider. Make sure the way you calculate pixel is correct then it good to go.

```
driver.get("https://emicalculator.net/");
WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loaninterestslider\"]"));
int PixelsToMove = GetPixelsToMove(Slider, 15, 20, 5);
Actions move = new Actions(driver);
Action action = (Action) move.dragAndDropBy(Slider, PixelsToMove, 0).build();
action.perform();
```

Import package

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sliderwidth is basically just 100% of the size here but you can add whatever pixel you want.

```
    driver.get("https://emicalculator.net/");
    WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"loaninterestslider\"]"));
    Dimension sliderSize = Slider.getSize();
    int sliderWidth = sliderSize.getWidth();
    int xCoord = Slider.getLocation().getX();
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
    builder.moveToElement(Slider)
               .click()
               .dragAndDropBy
                 (Slider,xCoord + sliderWidth, 0)
               .build()
               .perform();
```

Import

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://emicalculator.net/");
    WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#loanamountslider span"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.clickAndHold(a).moveByOffset(500, 0).perform();
```

Here you go , you have to click the slider element and drag it

Comment: i want a function which can move a slider to an specific value like function(webelement slider,int value)  so that function should move the slider to that value. So that i can use the same function to automate other sliders too.like function(sliderElement1,50) , function(sliderElement2,90)

Answer (score 0):

As the topicstarter correctly mentioned, the question is about how to automate **any slider**. So let me extend existing answers with requested solution.

The solution is not new - Selenium already has sample with [Select](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html). Let's build similar solution.

So assume we wanted to have some object of type `EmiSlider` so we could use it the way:

```java
...
EmiSlider slider = new EmiSlider(driver.findElement(By.id("loanamountslider")));
slider.slide(100);
...
```

We are explicitly mentioning the desired locator and passing into constructor of class `EmiSlider`. The `EmiSlider` class then would be:

```java
public class EmiSlider {
    private final WebElement sliderRoot;
    private final WebDriver driver;

    public EmiSlider(WebElement slider) {
        // Simply store passed root WebElement
        this.sliderRoot = slider;
        // We require driver instance for internal use so resolve it and store
        this.driver = ((WrapsDriver) slider).getWrappedDriver(); 
    }
    
    /**
     * Moves slider left or right
     * @param x pixels to move slider by. Positive value moves right, negative - left
     */
    public void slide(int x) {
        // Find the slider WebElement, which is child of root element, using relative search
        WebElement sliderElement = this.sliderRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("span"));
        // Perform slide action
        new Actions(this.driver)
                .clickAndHold(sliderElement)
                .moveByOffset(x, 0)
                .release()
                .perform();
    }
}
```

The current slider implementation had few drawbacks:

- It does not count on the current and extreme positions
- Different sliders might have different scales (and they do)
- The amout inputs are left alone while

Hope one can add missed functionality